# JS fetch: can I cache the same data identified by an ETag, but with a different URL?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am downloading data via HTTP GET using the JS fetch API.

The server 301 redirects me to a unique URL every time, but the ETag of the content of that URL is the same.

I think the unique URL is preventing caching from occurring.

Is it possible to rely on just the ETag and ignore the URL?

Comment: I don't think so. Caching is by URL, and ETag is just used to tell whether that URL has changed. Otherwise you would have a problem if two unrelated URLs accidentally used the same ETag.

Comment: But if ETag is a hash of the content, it would be ok - in this case it looks like the server is using a hash of the content (and not just a hash of the last modification date or a version number).

Comment: There's no requirement that any particular algorithm be used to generate ETag. Different sites may use different algorithms, and inadvertently have collisions.

Comment: Can you fix the server?

Comment: You could use a ServiceWorker to intercept the request and return a previously cached response, using a previous request as key.